# Optimise nested manager

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I was wondering how I can optimize the python code below? If you are curious, the code is for a custom permissions class in DRF/Django.

The permissions check is there to see if the currently logged in user is the manager of user who created the object, or managers manager and so on.

```
class IsManager(permissions.BasePermission):
    """

    """

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):

        user = request.user

        if hasattr(user, 'manager'):
            if user == obj.user.manager:
                has_permission = True
            else:
                has_permission = False

        elif hasattr(user.manager, 'manager'):
            if user == obj.user.manager.manager:
                has_permission = True
            else:
                has_permission = False

        elif hasattr(user.manager.manager, 'manager'):
            if user == obj.user.manager.manager.manager:
                has_permission = True
            else:
                has_permission = False

        elif hasattr(user.manager.manager.manager, 'manager'):
            if user == obj.user.manager.manager.manager.manager:
                has_permission = True
            else:
                has_permission = False

        elif hasattr(user.manager.manager.manager.manager, 'manager'):
            if user == obj.user.manager.manager.manager.manager.manager:
                has_permission = True
            else:
                has_permission = False

        elif hasattr(user.manager.manager.manager.manager.manager, 'manager'):
            if user == obj.user.manager.manager.manager.manager.manager.manager:
                has_permission = True
            else:
                has_permission = False

        else:
            has_permission = False

        return has_permission
```

cheers
James

---

Updated with working code (thanks Alex Hall) with lots of comments that help people like me :)

```
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):

        user = request.user
        manager = obj.user  # Assign user as initial source for checking if manager is specified
        while True:
            print("Manager: ", manager)
            # First loop, manager = obj.user and is checking if obj.user.manager is true, otherwise sets manager to None
            # 2nd loop, manager is now obj.user.manager, otherwise sets manager to None
            # 3rd, 4th loops etc
            # this just keeps going until `manager` doesn't exist in which case the method returns false = permission denied
            manager = getattr(manager, 'manager', None)

            # It no manager then return false = permission denied
            if not manager:
                return False

            # If manager does exist, then check if the logged in user is the manager, if so return true = permission granted
            if user == manager:
                return True
```

Comment: How could this be true `hasattr(user.manager, 'manager')` if `hasattr(user, 'manager')` is false?

Comment: I don't know what `obj` is, but I would create a method on `obj` that returns the list of managers and then test if `user in obj.managers()`. Also your logic is totally wrong, you're testing if `user` has attribute `manager` but then use `obj.user.manager` which is a different user. And what FiddleSix said.

Comment: Thanks guys, I realize now how crazy wrong this is. @dirkgroten creating a method that gives me a list of managers is perfect, but these nested things are hurting my brain for some reason. Can you give any pointers? Happy to delete this question and post a new one if that's better/cleaner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
    user = request.user
    manager = obj.user
    while True:
        manager = getattr(manager, 'manager', None)
        if not manager:
            return False
        if user == manager:
            return True
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, this works but only for the first level. The area I am stuck is the looping down multiple manager levels.

Comment: Is this not doing that? With each iteration you go a level deeper with `manager = getattr(manager, 'manager', None)`